# Go installs latest version of dependency even if specific version is mentioned in go.mod

Tags: go

I am installing [golint](https://github.com/golang/lint) package in my CI pipeline and I am using Go v1.16. Now because of `golint`, it installs `sys` v0.2.0 even if golint's `go.mod` file has specific versioned dependencies.

- `golint` installs `golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200130002326-2f3ba24bd6e7`  (https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/go.mod)
- `gotools` installs `golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190620200207-3b0461eec859` (https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/2f3ba24bd6e75104fb11be4edf062de340ffd1ab/go.mod)
- `x/net` installs `golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a` (https://github.com/golang/net/blob/3b0461eec859c4b73bb64fdc8285971fd33e3938/go.mod)

Which is not `v0.2.0`. But still `sys` having `v0.2.0` is being installed and because of that other code/stages fails with error:

```
/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0/unix/syscall.go:83:16: undefined: unsafe.Slice    
/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0/unix/syscall_linux.go:2255:9: undefined: unsafe.Slice    
/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0/unix/syscall_unix.go:118:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice    
/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0/unix/sysvshm_unix.go:33:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
```

I have also checked release dates for `sys` here: https://github.com/golang/sys/tags and the above mentioned `sys` version is from past (from 2019) and it should work with Go v1.16.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Start by using Go 1.19. 1.16 is no longer supported.

Comment: Agree, but that's large change as compared to this. Shouldn't we able to fix this? I mean even if exact versions are mentioned, it's installing latest dependency.

Comment: Go will pick the minimum compatible version, so if a dependency requires a greater version that is the minimum version required. The `x/sys` packages are developed in sync with the Go runtime, so for a current runtime the latest package should be used anyway. (and why install the deprecated `golint` package at all at this point?)